# How make middle size video watching painless in website?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have a 63MB video in my website. It should start to play right after opening the site, but instead of it, it hung up for 20-30 sec.

I have choose the minimal resolution 720p, H-264 encoding. What elso I can do increase user experience?

You can see here the loading time:

https://sendmade-portal-vercel.vercel.app/hu/product/zer-jewel-rez-gyertyatarto

This is how `video` is used:

```js
<video
  ref={videoRef}
  width="100%"
  muted
  loop
  playsInline
  controls={props.isControlsVisible == true}
  autoPlay={props.isAutoplay == true}
  style={{
    width: "100%",
    height: "auto",
    zIndex: -1,
  }}
```

Comment: How would you suggest transfer 63MB? It can take up to 1 minutes with 4g... I guess there won't be leg when 5g would be the standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

65 MB is too much to use video as a background.
You must comply with the following:

1. Your video must be silent (remove audio)
2. Use a default image (no matter how small your video is, it will take a few seconds to load and display it)
3. Delete the video in mobile size
4. Your video should be short (based on experience, the best offer is a 10 - 20 seconds)

You can use the **[HandBrake](https://handbrake.fr/)** program (it is free) to reduce the video size with minimal quality reduction. In the test, your video size was reduced to 7 MB (I use Very Fast 720p30 option and in video tab select 24FPS)